# Laravel routing error 404

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes

In my laravel project routing isn't working correctly. When I go to /exchange, I get error 404. Redictering works good.

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect('exchange');
});
Route::get('exchange', function() {
    return view('exchange');
});

Route::get('tos', function() {
    return view('tos');
});
Route::get('contact', function() {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');

});
```

And my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

What I have to do to repair my project?

Comment: Other routes are working ???

Comment: No, always is 404

Comment: Which laravel version are you use ?

Comment: It isn't my project, someone wrote this in june 2016

Comment: Please make exchange route outside of  Route::group and check it

Comment: Maybe apache problem?

Comment: Please restart and check

Comment: try to dd(1) on your route.

Comment: Routes outside of Group not working, but when I wrote echo instead redict in '/', it works.
And when I wrote echo in '/exchange' this not works (404).

Comment: What append if you try to go on index.php/exchange ?

Comment: Change it to `Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {` and check if it works...

Comment: Yes, when I write index.php/exchange it works. What I have to do to erase index.php

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important directive in Apache

`AllowOverride All`

Define it on the httpd.conf file so that your `.htaccess` and URL Rewrites are honored by the server.

> Blast it, allow all types of overrides.

```
<Directory "PATH_TO_PROJECT">
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

> The bare minimum to make it work. Only allow overrides that modify document types and rewrites.

```
<Directory "PATH_TO_PROJECT">
     AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

Comment: I added this in my apache2.conf. And after restart, when I go to site, I get Internal Server Error.

Comment: Check the logs for the exact error message. 500 Internal Server Error is too generic. Also, the path must point to the `/public` folder of your Laravel project that contains the `index.php` bootstrapper and Laravel `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

You Have To add :-

**AllowOverride All** to etc/apache2  ***apache2.conf*** file

```
<Directory /usr/share>

AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It will handle routing error.